# Simplify expressions in LLVM SSA

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

There is a pass that [breaks a constant GEP expression](https://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/safecode/branches/see/lib/ArrayBoundChecks/BreakConstantGEPs.cpp?view=co) out of an instruction's operand into its own instruction, so that such nested GEP expressions become explicit and are thus easier to work with in subsequent passes.

Now I have a similar problem.  This SSA Phi instruction ([link](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1PHINode.html)):

```
while.cond:                                       ; preds = %while.body, %entry
  %n.0 = phi %struct.Node* [ bitcast ({ %struct.Node*, i32, [4 x i8] }* @n1 to %struct.Node*), %entry ], [ %13, %while.body ]
  ...
```

contains a bitcast instruction ([link](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1BitCastInst.html)) as its "inlined" operand.  Exists there a pass which allows me to break up the SSA of a given module into its most basic instructions, essentially "un-inlining" such nested expressions to make them explicit SSA instructions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any such pass.

However, it looks to me that modifying SAFECode's `BreakConstantGEPs` pass to do that should be very easy: just change the condition to be initially inserted into the worklist to be `isa<PHINode>` instead of an operand loop checking `hasConstantGEP`.

Comment: I thought about starting from that pass, yes. But since that pass is a little outdated I was hoping that a more recent implementation is available, one that's actually being maintained as well...

Comment: @Jens You have a point, I'm just not sure you'll be able to find one. These kinds of passes don't really appear in LLVM core itself, as it relies on constant folding to just sort it out.

Comment: Just make sure that you lift an inlined expression into the right basic block. You can't just put it in front of a phi instruction.

Comment: @SK-logic actually the pass he linked already takes care of that.